# How do i start a program from where it left off after shutdown and reboot

Tags: shutdown

I would like to know how to resume a program from where the program left after a system shutdown and once the system is powered back on.
To be clear i have a program that needs the system to shut down and restart before it can execute a condition i want to know how i would continue execution from the condition that is supposed to run once rebooted

Comment: Like, save a state file in AppData. Assuming it is windows, of course - you were not specific on that point

Comment: Sorry it is a Linux machine Debian Stretch to be exact

Comment: so put it in `/tmp`. But, frankly, it's hard to imagine a program that *needs to* reboot a Linux machine in the first place. You don't specify what is the functionality of your program - but if you've never done it before, maybe it's better to ask somebody for hands-on help

Comment: It's not really needed i am just curious on how it is done

Answer (score 1):

It's completely dependent on the program to implement that functionality.  Very little, if anything you can do if the program itself is not providing it.

If it's a program you are writing then you need to be more specific about what it does and what it is written in.  (Even then, it's quite hard to  explain)

Comment: I am writing the program that is why i wanted to know